# Authenticate a facebook user in a Firefox plug-in

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, firefox-addon

I'm trying to write a Firefox plug-in that accesses data from facebook. 
Now I'm not sure how to get an access token.
I tried to implement the client side flow for desktop apps (with the fixed redirect uri), but the big problem I encounter there, is that JavaScript doesn't allow me to wait for the redirect to happen.
Any idea how this could be done?

As far as I understood it, because I don't have a webpage, the JavaScript API doesn't help much, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "JavaScript API"? The [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/) or a classic XUL-based extension?

Comment: I meant the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) provided by facebook

Comment: No, that JavaScript SDK doesn't help much - you cannot load it into your extension due to security implications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are opening `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth` in a browser tab to let the user log in and give you access. You don't need to pass a working redirect URL here, you can rather use something that will definitely not work, like `http://my.extension.local/`. Then you only need to detect when the tab gets redirected to that URL. If you have a classic extension, you register a [progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) on the `<browser>` element of that tab and look at `onLocationChange()` calls - once you see a location starting with `http://my.extension.local/` you can cancel the request and close the tab, the necessary data is in the URL. If you use the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/) you can attach a `ready` event listener to the tab, something along these lines:

```
var tabs = require("tabs");
tabs.open({
  url: "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...",
  inBackground: false,
  onReady: function(tab)
  {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("http://my.extension.local/") == 0)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I have a regular extension and tried that: `var facebook = {
init: function() {
 var app_id = 'MY APP ID';
 var redirect_uri = 'fb.com/login_success'
        var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...'        window.open(url);

   window.addEventListener("load", function() {
     browser.addProgressListener(fbListener, Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_LOCATION); 
    }, false);
  }
};` But the code is never called. I also tried to just listen on page loads, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @wiseveri: So you are opening a new window but don't keep a reference to it. Instead you listen for the "load" event of the window you are in (which doesn't happen of course because the window is already loaded). And should that event hypothetically fire you are trying to access a variable called `browser` which isn't defined anywhere of course. Heh...

Comment: Exactly... changed that to: `var myWindow = window.open(url); myWindow.addEventListener('load', function() { gBrowser.addProgressListener(myListener);}, false);` and still nothing. How do I access the `<browser>` element of my new window? My method doesn't work obviously. The pages on Progress Listeners and browser elements didn't help either

Comment: That's a closure - you are accessing the `gBrowser` variable of your own window. Use `myWindow.gBrowser`.