# Why i can't load the Facebook SDK into Firefox Extention?

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox-addon, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have seen this Post: 
[Authenticate a facebook user in a Firefox plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383794/authenticate-a-facebook-user-in-a-firefox-plug-in)
and in the third comment someone said, that it isn't possible to load the facebook sdk into a firefox extension. But why?

Comment: Add your comment below his, he'll reply. No need to add another question for this.

Comment: I vae tried, but there is no "Add comment"-button.

Comment: Ah right, you'll need more privs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript SDK provided by Facebook relies on a script from `connect.facebook.com` to be inserted into a web page. However, when you are an extension you don't have a web page around to load this script - you have extension pages. These extension pages are privileged, loading the script into them would give that script permission to do things like reading files on user's disk drive (or simply format it). Doing that with a script on some remote server is a pretty big security risk even if Facebook is considered a trusted site - its servers could get hacked or the traffic might be intercepted and modified. An attacker could then essentially take over user's computer.

Getting an unprivileged context for the Facebook SDK is theoretically possible. Practically however this is complicated enough that I doubt anybody has done it (it's further complicated by the fact the App IDs are bound to a specific host name).